# Email server for windows

Tags: windows, email, email-server

Look for a good email server for windows other than exchange server

do you guys have any recommendations?

only need IMAP/POP3/SMTP and SSL support

for small biz use, no more than 100 users 20 domains

Comment: How many users / what kind of load? Any groupware needs? Active Directory integration? Giving us more details could prove beneficial to your quest.

Comment: A explanation as to why you don't want to use exchange would be handy.

Comment: Exchange is sometimes a bit "heavy" on both the hardware and the wallet.  But still, why not Exchange?  Price?  Hardware not beefy enough to handle it?  License issues?

Answer (score 4):

I've tinkered with hMailServer.

http://www.hmailserver.com/

Comment: +1 for hMailserver. I used it for my personal domains with no issues. It can connect to SQL Server, which opens up a whole host of options.

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who swears by [IceWarp](http://www.icewarp.com/).

No discussion of Exchange alternatives is complete without mentioning [Kerio](http://www.kerio.com/mailserver)!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another vote for [hMailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/). I've been using it for about 9 months for those domains we don't want to include on our Exchange server (don't ask, that's just the way it is). I also use it for my personal domain and my family can access their email from anywhere via the webmail interface provided by the Squirrelmail. That's real handy when you're travelling.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a [alt-n MDaemon](http://www.altn.com/) installation with around 200 users a few years ago, and that company was happy with it. It is a product that has been around for years now.

For the small-biz space I'm quite happy with Kerio -- but I have never worked professionally with their [Kerio Mailserver](http://www.kerio.com/mailserver) product, so I have no direct experience with it. It gets very good reviews from [time](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/other-software/66251/kerio-mailserver-6) to [time](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1647148,00.asp)...

My solution of late has been [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html). I'm super-happy with it:

- Uptime is as good as any self-hosted solution in the smallbiz space will see
- The feature set works O.K. for smaller companies
- Having one system less to administer and maintain is a real relief.

Perhaps not ideal for your 20 domains requirement though -- you can [add domain aliases to a Google Apps account](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295), but I don't know how many it will take, and usernames will be shared across domains. One potential workaround is to make multiple accounts of course..

Comment: Upvoted for the Google Apps part. Can't speak to the other options.

Answer (score 0):

**Argosoft Mail Server**

I've been using the Argosoft mail server for years and its proven to work quite well.  It also has a very nice amount of spam filtering based on DNSBL, and Geo IP.

http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/MailServerNET/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Many use iMail (from IPSwitch), and claim great success. Never used it though, but probably something worth checking out.